# How to ask a question I when already have a solution that worked for me, but I'm not sure it will work for others?

Tags: discussion

I was having trouble with FreeBSD -- When I tried the `startx` command, it said `cannot start in framebuffer mode`.

Eventually I found a solution to this problem.  I assume many other newcomers to FreeBSD may run into the same problem, and I want to help them out.

But here's my question in this case -- I know I can post an answer to my own problem, but should I do this when I'm not sure it's the best approach?  I'm no FreeBSD export, so I'm not even sure my solution will work for others.  Would it be inappropriate to post a solution I'm not sure about?

On the other hand, I could post the the question without any answer, but that would also be weird because I know the answer (or at least I think I *might*).

Just wanted to know what the guidelines would suggest I do in this situation.

---

Also, here is the solution that worked for me:

- Install vim using `pkg install vim`, then type `y` when appropriate.
- Create a file using vim with `vim /usr/local/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/driver-inter.conf`
- Add this to the file:

  ```
  Section "Device" \
  Identifier "Card0" \
  Driver "scfb" \
  EndSection
  ```
- Save and exit vim, then use the `startx` command again.

Comment: We completely accept people answering their own questions, though there may be a delay of a day or two to accept your own answer. [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) we still require that you follow the Q&A format and post a complete self contained question detailing your problem and diagnostic steps, then posting an answer below that.

Comment: @Mokubai At first glance (especially given the title), I agree that this appears to a duplicate of the linked question, but it seems to me to be different enough that it could stand on its own.  It appears that the OP is already aware that they can self-answer, but their question is more around whether they *should* or not, given they aren't certain whether their answer is correct.  I'm going to make an attempt at an edit to see if it can be clarified.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thanks, I didn't know what to do. Thanks for helping out

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds  That the solution worked for him is enough for me to believe it is "I've got an answer" and so is perfectly acceptable. That doesn't stop other people posting other answers that may or may not be "more correct". Badasahog found a solution and that is what the dupe is asking whether it is okay to post. Emphatically the answer is "Yes, if you have a problem and you solved it then feel free to share it." The only thing to be wary of is if the problem duplicates another question then it may get closed that way, but even then that will link the question with another way to solve it.

Comment: @Mokubai Take a look at my edit and see what you think.  This one is more about, *"Is it appropriate to self-answer even if you aren't sure the answer is correct or will work for others?"*  I really don't feel the duplicate covers that (either the linked question itself or the answers to it).  Although it's entirely possible there's *another* question here on Meta that covers "answering even when I'm not sure."

Comment: @Badasahog Answering your question here in the comments though, in the meantime.  *Yes* - Post the question and your answer.  It's even okay to put in your answer something along the lines of, *"I'm not a FreeBSD expert, but this is what worked for me.  However, I'm not sure if it will work for others, and I'd definitely like to know if there's a more correct approach."* (use your own words, of course ;-)).  And don't be afraid of downvotes on the answer if it is wrong.  It's part of the learning experience that you are looking for.

Comment: @Badasahog As Mokubai said, though, do look for an existing duplicate first.  It's very possible that there's something related out here already.

Comment: I agree with @NotTheDr01ds.  Your question seems to be, basically, “Should I post an answer if I’m not 100% sure that it’s the best possible answer to the question?”  Why should it make a difference that you’re talking about a self-answer?  The answer is “Yes, post the answer if you believe that it might be useful (and not a duplicate) and you’re fairly sure it’s not harmful.”  We all do it.  If the answer isn’t perfect, join the club.  If it’s wrong, you may get a down vote or two.  Again, join the club.